# Adding column header to the CSV File

Tags: sql-server, csv, select, ssms, bcp

```
-- Alcatel section
DECLARE @AlcatelFileName VARCHAR(255)
SET @AlcatelFileName = 'C:\Vanrise\Bad_CDRs\Alcatel\AlcatelBadCDR_' + @YesterdayDate + '(Top 100).csv'

DECLARE @AlcatelCmd NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @AlcatelCmd = 'bcp "SELECT top(100) * FROM [MediationSTGCDR].[Mediation_ICX].[AlcatelBadCDR] WHERE [FileName] LIKE ''%' + @YesterdayDate + '%''" queryout "' + @AlcatelFileName + '" -c -t, -S 10.21.3.3 -T'

-- Execute the bcp command for Alcatel
EXEC xp_cmdshell @AlcatelCmd
```

I want to show the column header in the CSV file that we are creating.
Is there any hero here to solve this?

Comment: You have to UNION the select with another one that has headers, and then make sure you will be able to sort that correctly. Usually, this is somewhat complicated to achieve.

Comment: Aside... the `bcp` utility isn't [RFC 4180-aware](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) so if any of your exported data happens to contain line breaks, quotes or delimiter characters then the resultant .csv file will be "broken." Consider using a different tool, such as a PowerShell script that outputs via the `Export-Csv` cmdlet.

Comment: Blarg; honestly just *don't* (ab)use `xp_cmdshell` for this. Using SQL server to invoke a command line environment, to call a command line application, that *reconnects* to the server that invoked the shell, to export data is *not* the solution. If you need to do something similar, use Agent to Invoke Powershell, or (better) just use Powershell to start with. Or, alternatively, use an actual ETL tool such as SSIS.

Comment: I am creating an SQL job that automatically sends daily CSV files by email according to yesterday's date

Comment: You can create a SQL JOb that runs a powershell step (not a SQL Step) that does this.